# Microsoft Face API for Android

Tags: android, azure-cognitive-services

I am going through the Get Started tutorial for Microsoft's Face API for Android handhelds. As of right now, everything except for the recognition part works. I can browse through photos alright. However, the detect method somehow always returns null and so no red rectangle is drawn. If someone has already successfully gone through the tutorial, I would be grateful if you could help me. Here is the detect method:

```
public Face[] detect(InputStream image, boolean analyzesFaceLandmarks, boolean analyzesAge, boolean analyzesGender, boolean analyzesHeadPose) throws ClientException, IOException {
    Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<>();

    params.put("analyzesAge", analyzesAge);
    params.put("analyzesGender", analyzesGender);
    params.put("analyzesFaceLandmarks", analyzesFaceLandmarks);
    params.put("analyzesHeadPose", analyzesHeadPose);

    String path = ServiceHost + "/detections";
    String uri = WebServiceRequest.getUrl(path, params);

    ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    int bytesRead;
    byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];
    while ((bytesRead = image.read(bytes)) > 0) {
        byteArrayOutputStream.write(bytes, 0, bytesRead);
    }
    byte[] data = byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray();
    params.clear();
    params.put("data", data);

    String json = this.restCall.request(uri, "POST", params, "application/octet-stream");
    Type listType = new TypeToken<List<Face>>() {
    }.getType();
    List<Face> faces = this.gson.fromJson(json, listType);

    return faces.toArray(new Face[faces.size()]);
}
```

Comment: Have you checked how many bytes are being uploaded to the FaceApi? The code you have posted looks OK. Is it possible that the the InputStream you are passing in is already at the end of the stream after reading the image? You may need to reset the stream position to the beginning.

Comment: Don't quite know what you mean. Would you mind posting your suggested version of the code?

Answer (score 0):

It looks as if the code you have posted is fine. This makes me wonder if the issue might be with the InputStream you are passing in as the input parameter. It might be that having read the source into the InputStream the position of the stream is at the end and therefore when you read from it nothing is being uploaded to the api.

I was suggesting you check the amount of image data you are uploading:

```
byte[] data = byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray();
int length = data.length; // <- what is this value?
```

It might be necessary to reset the stream position to the beginning before reading it again. Something like this may be required before reading from `image`

```
if(image.markSupported())
{
    image.reset();
}
```

BTW, my java is very rusty so there might be better code to use but hopefully you get the gist.

Comment: thanks; however I just realised the faulty part of the code. "String json = this.restCall.request(uri, "POST", params, "application/octet-stream");" somehow does not work correctly. What might be the possible reason for that?

Comment: What do you mean by 'does not work correctly'? Did you add the check I suggested above and does it contain what looks like the right amount of data? What is the response from the FaceApi, is it returning success but no faces found or is it returning an error response?

Comment: The line in the comment does a request but for some reason the request doesn't work

Comment: I've given you a couple of suggestions to try in my answer which as far as I can tell you've ignored. I've asked some questions in the comment to track down the issue which you've ignored and instead just repeated 'it doesn't work'. That is not going to help people solve your issue. You said in your question that the code you've shown returns null which is the correct behaviour if the image you uploaded doesn't contain any faces. So assuming the image you are uploading does contain a face then I would check the image is being uploaded correctly. Which is back where we started.